# Attached convex "hulls"

Tags: algorithms, convex-polytopes, terminology, computational-geometry

Let $\mathcal{P}$ a finite set of points of a Euclidean $\mathbb{E}^n$ and take the union $\mathrm{U}(\mathcal{P})$ of all *closed* half-spaces defined by $n$ elements of $\mathcal{P}$ that contain only points of the convex hull $\mathrm{CH}(\mathcal{P})$ of $\mathcal{P}$

**Questions:**

- is there an established name and/or notation for the closed complement of $\mathrm{U}(\mathcal{P})$?
- how can the closed complement of $\mathrm{U}(\mathcal{P})$ be calculated efficiently?
- has the closed complement of $\mathrm{U}(\mathcal{P})$ already been encountered e.g. in computational geometry or statistical sampling?

I am tempted to call  $\mathrm{CH}(\mathcal{P})$ *detached* from $\mathcal{P}$ if the convex hull of closed complement of $\mathrm{U}(\mathcal{P})$ is a proper subset of $\mathrm{CH}(\mathcal{P})$ and *attached* otherwise.

**edit:**
an equivalent, but simpler definition for the closed complement of $\mathrm{U}(\mathcal{P})$ is:

"the intersection of all closed half-spaces that contain all inner points and at least $n$ points of $\mathrm{CH}(\mathcal{P})$".

**Illustration:**
[image]
attached vs detached hull

in case of a detached convex hull there exists a hyperplane through $n$ points of $\mathcal{P}$ on the convex hull that cuts off an empty inner portion of the convex region defined b $\mathrm{CH}(\mathcal{P})$, whereas in the case of attached convex hulls such a hyperplane doesn't exist.

Comment: Isn‘t this just the region of Tukey depth 2?

Comment: @PatrickSchnider only in the case where the dimension is 2 and the convex hull of the pointset is detached; for higher dimensions and detached convex hulls it is set of points of Tukey depth $n-1$. Thanks for pointing me to Tukey depth; I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Is there an easy example where the convex hull is not detached?

Comment: @PatrickSchnider I added an illustration; hope it clarifies matters.

Comment: In the left picture, can‘t you cut off the topmost point using a line going through the rightmost point? Then the topmost point is not in your considered set, meaning the convex hull is detached? (I‘m probably missing something, sorry)

Comment: @PatrickSchnider the convex hull on the left is attached, because you can't cut off the topmost vertex of the convex hull. The left correponds to an orange without air between peeling and fruit, wheras the right one corresponds to one where the are some regions wit air between peeling and fruit.

Comment: Yes, that‘s how I interpreted it. But still there is a closed halfspace defined by a single point (the rightmost), which contains the topmost point in its interior. Unless I understand something wrong (which I probably do, sorry) this means that the convex hull is detached, right?

Comment: @PatrickSchnider please read my simplified definition in the edit, hich amounts to : if the intersection of all halfspaces that contain *all* inner points and $n-1$ points of the convex hull *is the same* as the intersection of all closed halfspaces that contain *all* points, *then* the convex hull is attached.

Comment: I see, I didn‘t see the simplified definition. However, I still don‘t see how this is equivalent to your original definition. Or do you maybe mean half-spaces defined by n points (instead of n-1)?

Comment: @PatrickSchnider sorry my fault; must of course be $n$ points.

Comment: Somehow my last comment didn‘t get uploaded, so let me try again: I think one way to compute your set might be to compute the convex hull and then checking for each extreme point whether removing it uncovers some interior points. If it does, we leave it in, otherwise we remove it and update the convex hull. This gives an overhead of O(nk^2), where k is the number of points, so in high enough dimensions the runtime is dominated by the computation of the convex hull. In lower dimension, some adaptation of a convex hull algorithm might give something faster.